# Using a MessageBox in Visual Studio 2010 how can I display a message, a timer int and then another message?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm making a small maze game and I'm stuck on one little issue, if the player wins I have a MessageBox pop up and give them a congratulatory message and display how long they took using the timer which I have counting how long they're taking as the game is played. The code I have for the message box is:

```
MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! You've beaten the maze! It took you: "+gameElapsed);
```

gameElapsed is the int for my timer. It's displaying the seconds after the text no problem, it's just getting text after that to say " seconds" is what I'm having trouble with.

So I want the MessageBox to say "Congratulations! You've beaten the maze! It took you: X seconds"

X being gameElapsed, the timer int.

I hope I've explained my problem clear enough, thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sorry, may you please illustrate what are you trying to exactly do? :)

Comment: So `gameElapsed` is an `int` containing the number of seconds it took them?

Answer (score 3):

I think `string.Format` is better:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Congratulations! You've beaten the maze! It took you: {0} seconds", gameElapsed));
```

---

Using
the `+` operator on nonliteral strings causes the concatenation to be performed at run time.
To concatenate
several strings together at run time, avoid using the `+` operator because it creates multiple
string objects on the garbage-collected heap.
Instead, use the `System.Text.StringBuilder` type or use `string.Format` method. (`string.Format` use `System.Text.StringBuilder` internally.)

I therefore recommend that:

- Using `string.Format` for small amount of strings, or we required a high level of readability.
- Using `System.Text.StringBuilder` for large number of strings.
- Using `+` for literal strings, the C# compiler concatenates them at compile time and ends up placing just one string.

Comment: @regulatethis I have updated my answer. Hope it make sense to you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this :

```
MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! You've beaten the maze! It took you: "+ gameElapsed + " Seconds");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! You've beaten the maze! It took you: "+gameElapsed.ToString() + " seconds");
```

Will print out:

Congratulations! You've beaten the maze! It took you: 4 seconds